# HTML how to make the whole page from right to left text?

Tags: html

so I want the whole website or the page to be from right to left text like dis

```
<bdo dir="rtl">I love Programming</bdo>
```

output:"gnimmargorP evol I"

but I want to this happens to the all the text in the page...so how?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate.

Comment: Html is static. I.E. You see what you type. If you want to flip all the text, use Javascript

Answer (score 1):

It feels like a bit of a hack but you can put this in your CSS file:

```
* {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left;
}
```

You can play with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9m50yd6/).

Using explicit classes might be better. Doing it in JavaScript or on the server side might be best. It depends what you're using it for.

Comment: Thanks bro :D but what do you mean with "a bit of hack"?

Comment: Well from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) "Note: This property is intended for DTD designers. Web designers and similar authors should not override it." If it's just something you're doing for fun it's probably ok but otherwise it might be better to look for javascript that reverses strings. Or do it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is some css:

```
div {
   direction: rtl;
}
```

maybe in your case

```
* {
   direction: rtl;
}
```

to select all

Comment: No not like dis...I want it to be Instead of "I love Programming" "gnimmargorP evol I" but in all the text of the page